# Can I delay the onSuccess method in RxJava?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java

I have `SplashScreenFragment` and inside this fragment, I'll load the data from the server using `Retrofit` with `RxJava`, Getting data from the server will take between 1 second to 25 seconds.

The `SplashScreenFragment` must show to the user for at least 8 seconds.

When I get the data from the server, The `onSuccess` method will be called and inside this the `onSuccess` method I'll navigate the user to the `HomeFragment`

**Let's take an example to understand what I want exactly:**

**First Scenario:** When I open the app, The `SplashScreenFragment` will be launched and it will get the data from the server, Let's suppose it took 1 second to get the data from the server, In this situation, It must not call with the `onSuccess` method, Should wait 7 seconds and after that, It must call the `onSuccess` method

**Second Scenario:** When I open the app, The `SplashScreenFragment` will be launched and it will get the data from the server, Let's suppose it took 3 seconds to get the data from the server, In this situation, It must not call with the `onSuccess` method, Should wait 5 seconds and after that, It must call the `onSuccess` method

**Third Scenario:** When I open the app, The `SplashScreenFragment` will be launched and it will get the data from the server, Let's suppose it took 12 seconds to get the data from the server, In this situation, Must call with the `onSuccess` method directly without waiting.

I can do that, But without `RxJava`, I want to know is there any method in `RxJava` to delay the `onSuccess` method depending on the conditions above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zip it with an 8 second timer:

```java
Single<Data> datasource = ...

datasource.zipWith(Single.timer(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (a, b) -> a)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(data -> { }, error -> { });
```