# How can I delay the onSuccess and onError methods in RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71662787/can-i-delay-the-onsuccess-method-in-rxjava) about how to delay the onSuccess method in RxJava about 9 months ago. Here is a summary of the question:

> The SplashScreenFragment is a fragment that loads data from a server
> using Retrofit with RxJava. The data may take between 1 to 25 seconds
> to be retrieved. The SplashScreenFragment must be shown to the user
> for at least 8 seconds. When the data is retrieved, the onSuccess
> method is called and the user is navigated to the HomeFragment.
>
> The goal is to delay the onSuccess method based on the time it takes
> to retrieve the data from the server. If it takes less than 8 seconds,
> the onSuccess method should be delayed for the remaining time. If it
> takes more than 8 seconds, the onSuccess method should be called
> immediately. Is there a way to do this using RxJava?

[The answer of akarnokd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71662917/7474282) worked for me and successfully delayed the onSuccess method. But I want to also delay the onError method because his answer did not delay the onError method. How can I do this using RxJava?

Comment: Use `datasource.materialize().zipWith().dematerialize(v -> v)`.

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you for your reply. Could you please explain how it works? I prefer not to simply copy and paste.

Comment: It wraps then unwraps the signals. They appear as simple values for the zipWith, so any error is not acted upon until dematerialize.

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you for the explaining. I'm not quite sure I understand, but I'll give it a try and see if that helps. Thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option1:

```
private fun setupSplashTimer() {
loadApiFromServer()
Single.timer(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doAfterTerminate {
        // this method will be called after 8 seconds
        // Next screen
    }
    .subscribe({
        // Call success
    }, {
        // Call error
    })
}

private fun loadApiFromServer() {
// Call api here
}
```

Option2: add `onErrorReturn { "" }` . this is sample

```
private fun setup() {
    Single.zip(loadApiFromServer().onErrorReturn {
        ""
    }, delayTimer()) { a, b ->
        Pair(a, b)
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({

        }, {

        })
}

private fun loadApiFromServer(): Single<String> {
    return Single.fromCallable {
        ""
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
}


private fun delayTimer(): Single<Long> {
    return Single.timer(8, 
TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
}
```

Comment: But the `doAfterTerminate` method will not delay the execution of the `onError` method.

Comment: @TahaSami I add option 2. Try it